# Is there a way to turn an array of strings into object collection?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, javascript-objects, converters

Basically, is from this `['padding', 'children', 'className']` to this:

```
{
    padding: "padding",
    children: "children",
    className: "className",
}
```

I had tried a few methods as follows:

```
const arr = ['padding', 'children', 'className'];

const obj = Object.keys(arr).map((prop) => ({ [prop]: prop }))`;
```

*Output:*

```
[{padding: "padding"}, {children: "children"}, {className: "className"}]
```

But the collections are like "independents" inside the array... Please, help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr = ['padding', 'children', 'className'];

const res = arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
  acc[item] = item; return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Could you please explain how it works? Thank you!

Comment: @JoãoVictor Basically it's a technique to iterate over the array where ``acc`` is initially set to an empty object ``{}`` to be updated. In each iteration, we use the element at the index (``item`` in this case) to add a new key-value pair to the object. In the end, the output would be a map of each unique item as a ``key`` and ``value``. I added a reference to the docs for more details.

Comment: what's the difference between use `reduce()` and `Object.fromEntries()`. Is there a "recommended" way?

Comment: @JoãoVictor both do the job here, but when using ``Object.fromEntries`` you need to iterate over the array and create the pairs before passing them to the function, whereas using ``.reduce`` saves the time in one iteration which is more straight-forward in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and `map` it to key value pair form:

```js
const arr = ['padding', 'children', 'className'];

const result = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(k=>[k,k]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a simpler solution than use `reduce()` I guess...

Comment: **Just for fun:** You can abuse a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to do the mapping for you `const obj = Object.fromEntries(new Set(arr).entries());` but please, this is no serious suggestion. Don't do this in production. At least not without like 10 lines of comments what's happening here and why you chose to do it this way.